# Fatal Error when i go to admin->manage category

Tags: magento-1.8

I get this error when I go to "Manage Category" in admin side.

> ```
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 
> '/home/shopnow/public_html/errors/report.php' (include_path='/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/local:/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/community:/home/shopnow/public_html/app/code/core:/home/shopnow/public_html/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/shopnow/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 925
> ```

when I go to error folder, I couldn't found report.php.
what should I do to see "manage category" again?

Comment: You can try to format your post - for a better readability

Comment: i am looking for solution.